# Upload featured image for a post from my plugin in Wordpress

Tags: php, file-upload, wordpress

In my plugin, what I am trying to do is let the admin upload a featured image for a post if it doesn't have one.
Below is my code that would display the featured image thumbnail if it exists, and show the add image button if it doesn't.

I am not sure how can I take forward the implementation of Add Image button. What kinds of hooks and filters am I looking at ?

```
<div class = "ft_homepage_modal_content">
  <button ng-hide = "postData.post_thumbnail_src" class="btn" ng-click="">Add Image</button>
  <div ng-show = "postData.post_thumbnail_src" >
    <img ng-src = "{{postData.post_thumbnail_src}}" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the required code for your wordpress theme to add the featured images support (add it on functions.php on your theme)

```html
<?php
function wptutsplus_theme_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wptutsplus_theme_support' );?>
```

after that you can add to your theme: `the_post_thumbnail();` (on The Loop) or `get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr );`

See the source:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-wordpress-theme-from-static-html-adding-featured-images--wp-34230

Comment: I am creating a plugin, not a theme. So there is no functions.php. 
I am using get_the_post_thumbnail function to get the featured image, but what if a featured image does not exist. For those situations I want to give user the ability to upload it on button click.